# jQuery Multiple Star Rating system using Select Option dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this simple jQuery Star rating system that I'd like to use, I am following http://jsfiddle.net/ code in my website and it's working fine for one star rating system not for multiple and I have multiple star rating system on one page in my website.

Here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eeG86/

```
<select name="my_input" id="rating_simple">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>

 <select name="my_input" id="rating_simple">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>

 <select name="my_input" id="rating_simple">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>
```

In above link I had like jQuery drop down but this is working only for one rating system on one page. My problem is I have multiple star rating system on one page.

Comment: change the id's maybe you are facing problem because of same id's give them unique names

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is the fact that you're using IDs, let's alter your markup for each `select` to use a class:

```
<select name="my_input" class="rating_simple">
```

Now we need to update your jQuery to reflect the change (using `.` instead of `#`).

**Finally**, in your `change` method, you refer to the star rating system using `$(".webwidget_rating_simple")`, but now we have multiple of these in the DOM, so we need to refer to the one adjacent to the current `select` that you're changing, using `$(this).next(".webwidget_rating_simple")`.

So finally, your jQuery will look like this:

**EDIT** we actually need to setup each dropdown individually, this is to prevent the issue within the plugin that will select all dropdowns if you click on one star (it's better to alter the calling code than it is to update the plugin).

```
$(".rating_simple").each(function () {
    $(this).webwidget_rating_simple({
        rating_star_length: '5',
        rating_initial_value: '',
        rating_function_name: ''
    });
 });

$('.rating_simple').change(function () {
    $(this).next(".webwidget_rating_simple").children("li").css('background-image', 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//nst.gif)');
    $(this).next(".webwidget_rating_simple").children("li").slice(0,this.value).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//sth.gif)');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eeG86/16/)

Comment: it seems you only update the dropdown change events, if i click in the stars, the dropdown value won't update correctly:)

Comment: Yes, You are right your suggestion works for me. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Yes, you are right huan .. when i click on stars all dropdown menu will change the value instead of one .

Comment: @user3932382 I've fixed that, see my new link here: http://jsfiddle.net/eeG86/16/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. use different id and name.

```html
<select name="my_input1" id="rating_simple1">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>

 <select name="my_input2" id="rating_simple2">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>

 <select name="my_input2" id="rating_simple2">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="1">Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
                    <option value="3">Average</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
                </select>
```